# while clicked on navbar button url is change but Content is not load in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Whenever i clicked on button url is change but content doesn't change and one more thing if i use `<a> tag` in exchange of `<Link> tag` then obviously page loading but content also load and update
but using `<Link> tag` it is not load data but url value is update so, please give me a solution for this

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Home from "./component/pages/Home";
import Contect from "./component/pages/Contect";
import About from "./component/pages/About";
import Navbar from "./component/layout/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
     
<Navbar title="title1" />
      
<Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Contect" component={Contect}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/About" component={About}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
      <div className="container">
        <Link class="navbar-brand bg-light" to="/contect">
          {props.title}
        </Link>

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <Link class="nav-link bg-light" to="/">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <Link class="nav-link bg-light" to="/About">
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**Home.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    
    const Home = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="py-4">
              <h1> Home page </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

**`About.js and Contect.js is same as Home.js`**

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router>  
  <Navbar title="title1" />   
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/Contect" component={Contect}/>    
    <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: no it's not working